# Can't create table in YugbyteDB in multi region deployment with preferred region

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I deployed a 3 master + 3 tserver cluster on 3 different regions. I am trying to set a preferred region.

Even though each master is in a different region, I had to use https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#modify-placement-info so that is appeared in the config.
I then used : https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#set-preferred-zones to set the preferred zone.

But the tablets are not rebalancing the leaders. Is there anything else to do ?

sample yb-tserver.conf

```
/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-tserver \
--fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0 \
--tserver_master_addrs={yb-master-0.yb-masters.yugabyte1.svc.cluster.local:7100,nyzks901i:29600},ldzks449i:29605,sgzks449i:29601 \
--placement_region=nyz-core-prod \
--use_private_ip=never \
--server_broadcast_addresses=nyzks902i:29500 \
--metric_node_name=yb-tserver-0 \
--memory_limit_hard_bytes=3649044480 \
--stderrthreshold=0 --num_cpus=0 \
--undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql \
--rpc_bind_addresses=yb-tserver-0.yb-tservers.yugabyte1.svc.cluster.local \
--webserver_interface=0.0.0.0 \
--enable_ysql=true \
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=0.0.0.0:5433 \
--cql_proxy_bind_address=yb-tserver-0.yb-tservers.yugabyte1.svc.cluster.local
```

sample yb-master.conf

```
/home/yugabyte/bin/yb-tserver \
--fs_data_dirs=/mnt/disk0 \
--tserver_master_addrs={yb-master-0.yb-masters.yugabyte1.svc.cluster.local:7100,nyzks901i:29600},ldzks449i:29605,sgzks449i:29601 \
--placement_region=nyz-core-prod \
--use_private_ip=never \
--server_broadcast_addresses=nyzks902i:29500 \
--metric_node_name=yb-tserver-0 \
--memory_limit_hard_bytes=3649044480 \
--stderrthreshold=0 \
--num_cpus=0 \
--undefok=num_cpus,enable_ysql \
--rpc_bind_addresses=yb-tserver-0.yb-tservers.yugabyte1.svc.cluster.local \
--webserver_interface=0.0.0.0 \
--enable_ysql=true \
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=0.0.0.0:5433 \
--cql_proxy_bind_address=yb-tserver-0.yb-tservers.yugabyte1.svc.cluster.local
```

Even creating a new table results in errors:

```
cur.execute(
...   """
...   CREATE TABLE employee (id int PRIMARY KEY,
...                          name varchar,
...                          age int,
...                          language varchar)
...   """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Invalid argument: Invalid table definition: Timed out waiting for Table Creation
```

And following yb-tserver logs after the error above:

```
W0806 15:00:55.004124    63 catalog_manager.cc:7475] Aborting the current task due to error: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:7623): An error occurred while selecting replicas for tablet 0a503b0b9196425c956a8b9939b2c370: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:7623): Not enough tablet servers in the requested placements. Need at least 3, have 1: Not enough tablet servers in the requested placements. Need at least 3, have 1
E0806 15:00:55.004171    63 catalog_manager_bg_tasks.cc:142] Error processing pending assignments, aborting the current task: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:7623): An error occurred while selecting replicas for tablet 0a503b0b9196425c956a8b9939b2c370: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:7623): Not enough tablet servers in the requested placements. Need at least 3, have 1: Not enough tablet servers in the requested placements. Need at least 3, have 1
I0806 15:00:55.139647  2352 ysql_transaction_ddl.cc:46] Verifying Transaction { transaction_id: bb93b749-6b57-41b6-8f50-7461a07dc254 isolation: SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION status_tablet: 4069e18783a747bea31895b3ab6c69f6 priority: 1756854571847405073 start_time: { physical: 1628261964493502 } }
I0806 15:00:55.295994    53 ysql_transaction_ddl.cc:77] TransactionReceived: OK : status: PENDING
status_hybrid_time: 6669361378174894079
propagated_hybrid_time: 6669361378174910464
I0806 15:00:55.296051    53 ysql_transaction_ddl.cc:97] Got Response for { transaction_id: bb93b749-6b57-41b6-8f50-7461a07dc254 isolation: SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION status_tablet: 4069e18783a747bea31895b3ab6c69f6 priority: 1756854571847405073 start_time: { physical: 1628261964493502 } }: status: PENDING
status_hybrid_time: 6669361378174894079
propagated_hybrid_time: 6669361378174910464
W0806 15:00:55.310122    66 master_service_base-internal.h:39] Unknown master error in status: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:7623): An error occurred while selecting replicas for tablet 0a503b0b9196425c956a8b9939b2c370: Invalid argument (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:7623): Not enough tablet servers in the requested placements. Need at least 3, have 1: Not enough tablet servers in the requested placements. Need at least 3, have 1
I0806 15:00:55.496171  2352 ysql_transaction_ddl.cc:46] Verifying Transaction { transaction_id: bb93b749-6b57-41b6-8f50-7461a07dc254 isolation: SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION status_tablet: 4069e18783a747bea31895b3ab6c69f6 priority: 1756854571847405073 start_time: { physical: 1628261964493502 } }
I0806 15:00:55.652542    67 ysql_transaction_ddl.cc:77] TransactionReceived: OK : status: PENDING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Dorian's answer: please show and validate the full placement info. You can do this in the following way:

- The master placement info can be found using `curl http://MASTER-ADDRESS:7000/api/v1/masters | jq`.
- The tserver placement info can be found on `http://MASTER-ADDRESS:7000/tablet-servers` (via a browser).
- The preferred zones overview using `curl http://MASTER-ADDRESS:7000/cluster-config | jq`

That way, it should be easy to see and validate if everything is set as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You also need the `--placement_cloud=cloud` and `--placement_zone=rack1` arguments to your yb-tserver processes (to match what you passed to `modify_placement_info` step). Not just the `--placement_region` gflag.

Otherwise, the `create table` step doesn't find matching TServers to meet the desired placement for the table.